# Identigy Next Week in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, date, datetime

I have a form which user submits and I get the current time and date in the database and facebook ID of the user as well, As per rule the user can fill the form only once in a week, so if he fills the form on Tuesday, he is not eligible to fill the form unless the week is complete, (Only eligible to complete the form again on next Monday)
I am trying to find some php function for weeks but couldn't get so, Anyone can help me what can be done for this logic?
I have date/time in the db for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are basically looking for

`$date = "2014-10-13";
$week=date("W", strtotime($date));`

or even use it this way

`$date = "2014-10-13";
$date = new DateTime($date);
$week = $date->format("W");`

( http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php )